# What does question mark (?) mean in webpack's entry?

Tags: javascript, webpack, syntax, webpack-dev-server

I'm learning webpack and came across an example webpack.config.js that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3030',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/boot.js'
    ],
...
```

I could not find any specification of the use of question mark in this case, but I assume it's like a parameter to the module `webpack-dev-server/client`, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a specifically for `webpack-dev-server/client` only. This is a common way to add `webpack-dev-server/client` to the bundle for automatic refresh.

The signature looks like: `webpack-dev-server/client?http://<path>:<port>`